# How to move characters position in a String to achieve a date format?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, date-formatting

In Java (Android Studio) I have a string that I get from a database (Firebase) like this `20190329` which is a date but I would like to print it out in this format: `29-03-2019`. So, I just need to move `2019` to the end of the string and `29` to the beggining. I know this can be done by using a loop but is there a simpler way to achieve it?

I already have this code that adds the `-` and works well:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(date); //the variable 'date' contains 20190329 or any other date from the database.
sb.insert(2, "-");
sb.insert(5, "-");
sb.insert(8, "-");
```

Comment: A two-step aprocah is to use a date formatter and convert your string to a LocalDate object and then convert that object back to a string in the format you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use str.substring()**

Try by doing this. The substring method returns a substring from the begin index to the end one.

```
String day = data.substring(6,8);
String month = data.substring(4,6);
String year = data.substring(0,4);
String newDate = day + month + year;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(date); //the variable 'date' contains 20190329 or any other date from the database.
sb.insert(2, "-");
sb.insert(5, "-");
sb.insert(8, "-");
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer has worked! However, I had to fix something on it, so apparently it was not taking the day, the month nor the year correctly. I don't know why but I have had to do this: ```String day = dataDB.substring(6,8);```, ```String month = dataDB.substring(4,6);``` and ```String year = dataDB.substring(0,4);```. It works well now :)

Comment: Yep. That was my wrong. Thank you for letting me know, I will edit the post so that other people have the good answer. Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 6):

You can and should use `java.time` in order to parse and format date objects:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // use a LocalDate and a DateTimeFormatter with a fitting format to parse the String
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("20190329", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
    // print it (or return it as String) using a different format
    System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")));
}
```

Output of this code is

```
29-03-2019
```

Most `java.time` functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.
Further adapted for earlier Android (< API Level 26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Oops, I am using Android Studio for this and apparently your code is not totally compatible as I get this on ```parse``` and ```ofPattern``` https://i.imgur.com/V6qC1fC.png

Sorry, I did not add the Android Studio tag in my question as I thought it would work in any Java IDE.

Comment: @AdriánT95 OK, why haven't you tagged the question accordingly? However, there is a backport, I will update my answer soon...

Comment: Ok thanks, almost done... I have added the implementation to my gradle but now I'm a bit confused: I only have the MainActivity class, is it there where I have to add ```AndroidThreeTen.init(this);```? Because I have added it there and the issue still persists. Note: I take the date in a different method than the ```onCreate()```

Comment: @AdriánT95 I would do so. You are not taking the date in a method that is called before `onCreate`, are you? Have you done a grable sync after having added the backport there?

Comment: Nope, I do not think so. I am getting the date in the ```onDataChange()``` method which is a required method after implementing ```ValueEventListener``` and ```ChildEventListener``` (both are Firebase interfaces) and yes, I did a gradle sync.

Comment: Put it in the `onCreate()` method of the `MainActivity`, that's exactly what's suggested in the [*How to use ThreeTenABP*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)

Comment: Weird, it doesn't work... Take a look at my code: https://i.imgur.com/lOh9mFe.png

Comment: @AdriánT95 That's really weird... implementation import is correct? Have you cleaned/rebuilt the project?

Comment: Yeah, I have just done a clean/rebuilt and same thing. I think I have added the implementation correctly: https://i.imgur.com/dNeXL3I.png

Comment: @AdriánT95 Looks OK, I couldn't find anything wrong with your gradle... Have you tried anything else like an IDE restart?

Comment: All I have tried is cleaning and rebuilding the project and now I have restarted the IDE and the issue still persists. I don't know, maybe I should try PauMAVA's answer as yours seems to not be working properly in my case. I like yours though since it only has two lines.

Comment: @AdriánT95 Take the answer that works for you. My one is good, but not perfect since you have to use a library which seems to not be working in every case. It's *not cool* in general that Android doesn't support `java.time` in all API levels.

Comment: True, I wish it was compatible with Android. I have finally taken PauMAVA's answer, it works well! Thanks anyway for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by converting your String to Date and then back to String (with your desired format).

Both actions can be achieved with the use of `SimpleDateFormat` class.

For example (wrapped code in a Test class to test it of course),

```
@Test
public void test() throws ParseException {

   String date = "20190329";

   Date date_ = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(date);

   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

   System.out.println("Formatted Date : " + sdf.format(date_));
}
```

will eventually print `Formatted Date : 29-03-2019`

Comment: The idea is right but don't use old types when there are much better ways using the java.time package

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I just throw another choice on the table, that's all. Anyway, thanks for the down vote, first time I get it for a correct answer.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is old and buggy and there is no reason to recommend it any longer when there are much better options. So one could really question if this is considered a correct answer.

Comment: Assuming that the original string contains a correct date and needs no validation, this answer is correct and IMHO deserves no downvote even though the `SimpleDateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. I tried with an incorrect string, `String date = "1234567QQ";` and got `Formatted Date : 07-08-1238`, a bit surprised myself.